# Windows hard disk read-only now Windows is removed

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I recently installed Ubuntu over Windows,
Windows is removed now and Ubuntu is installed
I forgot to turn off fast-boot, and now all Windows drives are read-only
I cannot open Windows and turn off fast-boot because Windows is removed 
Please give some suggestions or solution.
Thank you

Comment: If you do not have Windows, you really should not be using NTFS. It periodically needs chkdsk and defrag, neither of which you can do from Ubuntu. At minimum have Windows repair disk. Best to backup data since you can read it, and then reformat partition to ext4. You should have backups anyway. This may work to remove hiberfile. https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: what I did is I downloaded windows repair kit ISO, and Turn Disk Write Caching Off.
This solved my problem  https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27180-windows-10-recovery-tools-bootable-rescue-disk.html