# GNU GRUB opens directly upon booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I found other similar questions but my outputs are different.
Firstly, when I write ls with partition names I get same results

this is what I get:

```
ls
(proc) (hd0) (hd1) (hd2) (hd2, gpt6) (hd2, gpt5) (hd2, gpt4) (hd2, gpt3) (hd2, gpt2) (hd2, gpt1) (hd3)

ls (hd0)/
error: invalid sector size 65535
ls (hd1)/
error: unknown filesystem
ls (hd2)/
error: unknown filesystem
ls (hd2, gpt1)/
efi/ en-us/ bootsect.bak
ls (hd2, gpt2)/
efi/ en-us/ bootsect.bak
ls (hd2, gpt3)/
efi/ en-us/ bootsect.bak
ls (hd2, gpt4)/
efi/ en-us/ bootsect.bak
ls (hd2, gpt5)/
efi/ en-us/ bootsect.bak
ls (hd2, gpt6)/
efi/ en-us/ bootsect.bak
```

I get same files in all of hd2 in this and whenever I reboot, i get invalid filesystems in random partitions. I have dual booted win10 with ubuntu and I haven't updated windows in some time. I tried boot repair tool with usb but it didnt work, help!

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair With multiple drives never run autofix, only use Advanced Options.https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BqjyYnFxwf/  this was the pastebin repair's report.

Comment: Only ext4 partition is on the flash drive with the ISO.  Not sure then how you got full /EFI/ubuntu in ESP but no UEFI boot entry. Install on flash drive boots from USB drive boot entry. Your "Windows" boot entry was modified to boot using grub, see line 86 (should never be done, but was in past). Does entry 0006 UEFI boot Windows? You need to use your Windows repair disk to create correct UEFI boot entry. Or See IV & restore Windows entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand. Can you explain this in laymans term @oldfred

Comment: It does not look like you have installed Ubuntu. Or you deleted it and only have live installer. From UEFI one time boot key often f12 but same key you use to boot live installer should be an entry saying UEFI, does that boot Windows? And cannot really help on details for Windows repairs.

Comment: Yes, it does boot windows @oldfred

Comment: Make Windows repair disk, if you do not have one. And then fix Windows. Windows 10 repair disk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156795/windows-hard-disk-read-only-now-windows-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment1925839_1156795
Repair/backup/restore
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/3a747883-b706-43a5-a286-9e98f886d490/create-a-recovery-drive & 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options

Comment: it works now, thanks @oldfred, write this as an answer so I can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Your "Windows" boot entry was modified to boot using grub, see line 86 (should never be done, but was in past). Does UEFI boot entry 0006 "UEFI" boot Windows? You need to use your Windows repair disk to create correct UEFI boot entry.

Your "Windows Boot Manager" boot entry was modified to boot using grub, see line 86 in your report (should never be done, but was in past). Does entry 0006 "UEFI" boot Windows? From UEFI one time boot key often f12 but same key you use to boot live installer should be an entry saying UEFI, does that boot Windows?

You need to use your Windows repair disk to create correct UEFI boot entry. Or See IV for example efibootmgr entries & restore Windows entry:

[Dual boot Win 8 / Ubuntu loads only Win](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win)

Some links to Windows repairs:

[Windows hard disk read-only now Windows is removed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156795/windows-hard-disk-read-only-now-windows-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment1925839_1156795)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852/windows-create-a-recovery-drive

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options