# Cannot boot into Windows 10 (dual booting error)

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, boot-repair

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 to be able to dual boot with my existing Windows 10. After the install I wanted to go back to Windows 10, but there is no GRUB menu that prompts me to pick which OS I to boot. It just goes straight to Ubuntu 20.04. After going into my UEFI and trying to boot Windows 10 from there, I get a boot order error and it sends me back to Ubuntu.

It may have something to do with Windows 10 is in Legacy mode according to the results of Boot-Repair that I ran in Ubuntu.

```
The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode. 
You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
```

This is the link I got for the boot repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MqNQz5992n/.

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at sector 
    908892160 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks for (,gpt1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following 
    components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p8: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS CurrentSession on nvme0n1p1
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p3

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic root=UUID=231ffef0-7328-48de-b30e-63d4f4116b9d ro quiet splash DEEPIN_GFXMODE= vt.handoff=7


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot enabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,9999,0000
Boot0000  Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,eb5eca17-c790-4a10-a3e1-9049db782e3e,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(7,GPT,9e58818b-ea10-d946-9936-b648c7eabb9b,0x361cf000,0xfa800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* Solid State Disk  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-25-38-84-81-BA-3A-27)/HD(7,GPT,9e58818b-ea10-d946-9936-b648c7eabb9b,0x361cf000,0xfa800)..BO
Boot9999* USB Drive (UEFI)  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(16,0)..BO

4d5de9b92e5f3729724c60ce0541cb49   nvme0n1p5/Boot/bootx64.efi
bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   nvme0n1p7/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p7/BOOT/mmx64.efi
04cd9cb6ceccbde1ca100ed1cae0f429   nvme0n1p7/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p7/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p7/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p7/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p7   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, bootmgr,    is-winboot
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.96 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 81B593F5-464F-48C9-A1AF-4785F23519FB
              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1 806489414  888410111  81920698  39.1G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    567296  806489413 805922118 384.3G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 970330112  973905919   3575808   1.7G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 973905920 1000202239  26296320  12.6G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p6 888410112  907866111  19456000   9.3G Linux swap
nvme0n1p7 907866112  908892159   1026048   501M Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p8 908892160  908894207      2048     1M BIOS boot
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000H1:;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:413GB:413GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
1:413GB:455GB:41.9GB:ext4::;
6:455GB:465GB:9961MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
7:465GB:465GB:525MB:fat32::msftdata;
8:465GB:465GB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
4:497GB:499GB:1831MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
5:499GB:512GB:13.5GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, msftdata;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL    PARTLABEL
nvme0n1                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1 ext4     231ffef0-7328-48de-b30e-63d4f4116b9d 28623785-44c4-5c4e-aa69-f8e5a9415e57          
├─nvme0n1p2                                               5ff1f579-038f-4385-9be1-d423787404fa          Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     1CF8413BF8411504                     221d78af-4c8a-4b4c-90a1-281c6602731b Windows  Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     2C5CC6215CC5E624                     a324444e-e255-40cb-9c74-c849d9487f65          
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     B84CBFDD4CBF949A                     e7c6a971-9935-4fba-ade0-5be613e70550 RECOVERY Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p6 swap     95f4887e-4757-4638-a4ff-d6f577bd13d7 c00d0051-28ea-cf47-9912-7308c6b7cea8          
├─nvme0n1p7 vfat     BF47-D8C9                            9e58818b-ea10-d946-9936-b648c7eabb9b          
└─nvme0n1p8                                               3f0c5f86-a011-495e-a721-b72779ed22f5          

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

           Avail Use% Mounted on
nvme0n1p1  25.8G  27% /
nvme0n1p3 235.2G  39% /media/lua/Windows
nvme0n1p4 898.3M  49% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
nvme0n1p5   1.5G  88% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
nvme0n1p7 492.2M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1 rw,relatime
nvme0n1p3 ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
nvme0n1p4 ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
nvme0n1p5 ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
nvme0n1p7 rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   231ffef0-7328-48de-b30e-63d4f4116b9d
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-45-generic   231ffef0-7328-48de-b30e-63d4f4116b9d
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic   231ffef0-7328-48de-b30e-63d4f4116b9d
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p1/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=231ffef0-7328-48de-b30e-63d4f4116b9d /              ext4    defaults   0 1
UUID=95f4887e-4757-4638-a4ff-d6f577bd13d7 swap           swap    defaults   0 2

==================== nvme0n1p1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p1: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 399.032908440 = 428.458322944  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             3
 420.825877190 = 451.858344960  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 389.871863365 = 418.621725696  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 386.481230736 = 414.981061632  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic                  1
 389.871863365 = 418.621725696  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic                  1
 386.481230736 = 414.981061632  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 384.970366478 = 413.358783488  boot/initrd.img                                4
 390.089079857 = 418.854960128  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic               2
 384.970366478 = 413.358783488  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic               4
 390.089079857 = 418.854960128  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

=================== nvme0n1p1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17622 Aug 17 07:04 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Aug 17 07:04 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Aug 17 07:04 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Aug 17 07:04 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Aug 17 07:04 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Aug 17 07:04 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Aug 17 07:04 41_custom

=================== nvme0n1p7/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 231ffef0-7328-48de-b30e-63d4f4116b9d root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[88315]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 31791: /bin/bash

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
nvme0n1p1 into the MBR of nvme0n1.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix     

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB). 

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________


The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a dual boot system, how does the BIOS choose which bootloader to run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981382/in-a-dual-boot-system-how-does-the-bios-choose-which-bootloader-to-run)

Comment: @karel Which one of the answers would help me with my problem?

Comment: [Converting Ubuntu into BIOS mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/981415/)

Comment: Boot-Repair is wrong, you have Windows in UEFI boot mode on gpt drive, not legacy boot. But that is because you erased the original ESP with Windows UEFI boot files. And then should not have Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. It looks like you have installed Ubuntu in both BIOS mode and in UEFI mode. Only boot in UEFI mode. First you need to run Windows repairs. It should use new ESP to add its boot files & create new Windows UEFI boot entry using correct GUID/partUUID. Then grub, if UEFI boot, can find Windows to add to menu.

Comment: @oldfred How would I go about doing these repairs from either Ubuntu or through my HP UEFI?

Comment: You first need a Windows repair disk or installer with repair console. You cannot fix most Windows issues from Linux. It is missing boot & BCD files that are Windows files, not available with Linux. After fixing Windows and making sure it boots directly from UEFI, you probably need to rerun Boot-Repair in UEFI  mode to make sure both systems are booting in UEFI mode.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156795/windows-hard-disk-read-only-now-windows-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment1925839_1156795