# How do I get back into my windows 10 after deleting the windows boot manager partition during ubuntu install?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-10

I installed ubuntu and attempted to dual boot it with windows. I had windows first and attempted to add ubuntu. I deleted my windows boot manager on accident when creating my ubuntu partitions. I have all of my windows 10 files saved on a different partition, but I can't boot into them. To put this in better words. I have access to ubuntu linux OS only and I need a way to recover my windows efi boot manager or create a new one. I can't erase any of the data from my windows 10 that I have saved in a windows partition.

My partitions:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1 259:0 0 238.5G 0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1 0 400M 0 part
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2 0 954M 0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3 0 128M 0 part
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4 0 91G 0 part unknown
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5 0 8.2G 0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p6 259:6 0 111.8G 0 part ubuntu
```

It says the partition I made for my windows, nvme0n1p4 is "unknown". I do have grub2 installed. I had to manually install it and I tried my best to set it up, but it's not working either. I'm not sure what to do, any advice or help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Is Windows unknown since it hibernated? If Windows fast start up is on, it may not be shown correctly. Or if corrupted, it would need Windows repairs from your Windows repair/recovery disk. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  Do you have Windows entry in UEFI boot menu & does it work (not grub menu's entry). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156795/windows-hard-disk-read-only-now-windows-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment1925839_1156795

Comment: You can't fix this Windows problem with Ubuntu.  Windows still needs and uses its bootloader even if you use GRUB.  GRUB simply hands off to the Windows bootloader when Windows is chosen.  Use Windows' recovery tools or you could ask about this on SuperUser.  Be careful what things you choose to erase and always keep backups in case of mistakes or failures.

Comment: If I burn the iso for windows onto a flash drive will that have the boot repair system.